# How to block connection from eth1 through firewall daemon?

Tags: firewall, firewalld

I have Debian 11 using the new Firewall Daemon, and I have a device connected to eth1. I want to block all connections from internet or any IP other than the local IP in the range 10.147.20.0/24.

Is it possible using firewall? I tried block zone, internal but i can still `ping www.yahoo.com`.

[Update 1]

```
eth0 -> connected to internet
eth1 -> local devices ex. NAS
tap1 -> VPN
eth2 -> Update
```

I want the following policy:

```
tap1: should be able to surf through eth0
tap1: access eth1, eth2
eth1: communicate with tap1, eth2
eth2: communicate with tap1, eth1, eth0 to surf internet
```

I have also put eth1, eth2, tap1 into the same bridge br0

Comment: `10.147.20.0/24` is a network, not an IP. If eth1 has an IP in that network you can block connections outside the net by not assigning a gateway. Outside may be able to reach you but you wouldn’t know how to send a reply.

Comment: @doneal24: there is a --direct syntax, i tried this, but it does not stop pings yahoo. This command as far as i understand takes ip rule and puts it to firewall-cmd. firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -o enp1s0f0 -j DROP

Comment: `ip route` should return a line like `default via 10.147.20.1 dev enp1s0f0`. If you run `ip route del default` can you still ping yahoo? Adjust the route to delete based on your particular network setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue, in which i created a bridge br0, and masqueraded eth0 that has internet.

In such a case any interface connected to br0 will be open to the internet. It is not a firewall issue rather than a network design issue.

Solution:

1. First masqueraded eth0 to pass internet.
2. Second changed the bridge from using brctl into using openvswitch.
3. Then i added a firewall on the openvswitch using openflow to disable eth1 from surfing the internet using this rule.

   ovs-ofctl add-flow br0 "priority=200,ip,nw_dst=192.168.188.0/24,in_port=eth1,actions=drop"

Router address: 192.168.188.0/24